# Xperia S Backup & Restore: Could not back up media files and downloaded apps with data

Tags: backup, sony-xperia, sony-xperia-s

When I tried backing up my Xperia S, the default Backup & Restore would backup only system apps.

It says "Could not back up" for "Media files" and for "Downloaded apps with data".

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to back up media files or app data. They are in device's internal storage. If  you are performing a factory reset these datas wont be erased unless you select `Erase Internal Storage` when performing a factory reset.

If you still need to backup the media files or app data, connect your Xperia S to a PC and backup the files in the PC.